# How to bind a method in a custom directive to the parent scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

First foray into custom directives and getting a bit stuck on binding to a method in the parent scope.

So when I use my custom directive in my app:

```
<dropdown x-label="Stuff" x-divider="-"
      x-list = "listOfStuff"
      x-ng-model="id"
      x-change-select="controllerMethodToBeCalled(id)">
</dropdown>
```

The template is as follows and triggers the 'update' function in the directive controller on ng-change.

```
<div class="dropdown_container">
    <div class="select_label">{{label}}</div>
    <div class="select_divider">{{divider}}</div>
    <select class="dropdown_select" id="dropdownList"
            ng-model="ngModel"
            ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in list | orderBy:'name'"
            ng-change="update(ngModel)">
    </select>
</div>
```

The directive code is below and I can call the method in parent scope directly whcih works fine but I'd like to trigger the 'change-select' that I've bound function 'controllerMethodToBeCalled' passing the id. Otherwise the component is not truly self contained.

```
angular.module('myApp.component.dropdown', [])

.directive('dropdown', function() {

    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        require: "^ngModel",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            list: "=",
            ngModel: '=',
            changeSelect: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'component/dropdown/dropdown.tpl.html',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            attrs.$observe('label', function (value) {
                $scope.label = value;
            });
            attrs.$observe('divider', function (value) {
                $scope.divider = value;
            });

        },

        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.update = function(id){

             //replace this line with call to changeSelect passing id
             $scope.$parent.controllermethodToBeCalled(id);

          };
        }
    };
});
```

Probably very easy to fix but I just can't see it. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: `$scope.changeSelect()`?

Comment: Doesn't do it. Have tried that approach already. I'd have thought it would have worked as the method should pick up the id from the scope without requiring an argument.

Comment: Works for me: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YTSgpz5SVIZTkXOTUiQZ)

Comment: It sort of works. The method is triggered but the id is wrong and out of sync. Do you know if there is a way to pass the id from the controller update method to changeEvent? BTW loving Plunker that's a nice little sandbox for playing about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to call `$scope.changeSelect()`. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YTSgpz5SVIZTkXOTUiQZ?p=preview). If you don't want to use the `id` from a parent scope, but rather pass the `id` argument from the function, you can do that do:

```
$scope.update = function(id){
    $scope.changeSelect({id: id});
};
```

It basically says use the value of the local variable `id` for `id` in the expression `controllerMethodToBeCalled(id)`.